# Changing path from sdcard to resources/raw

Tags: android, filesystems

So I don't understand how to change path of file from example:
Actually I have example code:

```
final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
final String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";
```

but I don't really understand how to change code in the same structure but gave another path from resources(raw file);
For example, I need something like this:

```
final String uploadFilePath = "android.resource://com.example.sender/"+R.raw.*;
final String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";
```

Comment: Try writing only R.raw.*; something like this:

    final String uploadFilePath = R.raw.*;
    final String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";

I don't think there is any need for the reference here.

Comment: its don't work  i try it bellow

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question.....what exactly are you trying to achieve???? Add some more description or code.......

Comment: I wana to upload file from my device to server. Find the example with code (first code), but this code give me ability send file only from external storage.
in my case, i need send file which i create in my project which will be situate in .raw folder...and i really don't know how to change example code to my project